# Python : How to make label bold in kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I am using `Popup` widgets in `python-2.7` and `kivy`.Can someone help me?
1. How to make label bold ? (ex. `text: "make label bold"`)
2. How to change color of title ? (ex. `title : "change title color"`)

## test.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class abc(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(abc, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.open()


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return abc()


TestApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<abc>
    title : "change title color"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            Label:
                text: "make label bold"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Bold Label Text

There are two methods to making label's text bold. They are as follow:

### Method 1

Use `bold: True`

```
Label:
    bold: True
```

[Label » bold](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.bold)

> ```
> bold
> ```
>
> Indicates use of the bold version of your font.
>
> **Note**
>
> Depending of your font, the bold attribute may have no impact on your
>   text rendering.
>
> bold is a BooleanProperty and defaults to False.

### Method 2

Use [Markup text](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#markup-text), `markup: True`

```
Label:
    markup: True
    text: '[b]make label bold[/b]
```

## Change Title Color

Use title_color

```
<abc>
    title : "change title color"
    title_color: [1, 0, 0, 1]    # red title
```

[Popup » title_color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#kivy.uix.popup.Popup.title_color)

> ```
> title_color
> ```
>
> Color used by the Title.
>
> title_color is a ListProperty and defaults to [1, 1, 1, 1].

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

<abc>
    title : "change title color"
    title_color: 1, 0, 0, 1    # red title
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                bold: True
                text: "make label bold"

            Label:
                markup: True
                text: "[b]make label bold[/b]"

''')


class abc(Popup):
    pass


class PopupApp(App):
    title = 'Popup Demo'

    def build(self):
        self._popup = abc()
        return Button(text="press me", on_press=self._popup.open)


PopupApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to the API [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=bold#kivy.uix.label.Label.bold)

1. It is a boolean with default as False, So  you may use as:

     `Label:
           text: 'blah blah'
           bold: True`
2. You may try adding color with the following tag:

   `color: [0.941, 0, 0,1]`

That should show in red color. It uses the format as RGBA (A for Alpha/Opacity). You can use [this](http://doc.instantreality.org/tools/color_calculator/) tool to choose your color.